# -webkit-transform-origin-z in Chrome, Safari and Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, css, safari, mobile-safari

[image]

The image above depicts exactly the problem i am having with Chrome, Safari and Mobile Safari. It seems as if Chrome is handling the -webkit-transform-origin-z correctly while the other two browsers present different results. Please take a closer look at the red box and its position in all browsers.

The code used to reproduce this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1
{
position: relative;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
margin: 100px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#div2
{
-webkit-perspective: 500;
}

#div3
{
padding:50px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: red;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40% 200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"><div id="div3">HELLO</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You are welcome to suggest any clue that will lead to a unified solution!

Thank you.

Comment: Read this: 
http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm

Comment: All the browsers I am testing on are Webkit based, so this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

because your Safari window is in a different size which changes the parameters of the website. I realized the white square is not 200x200 either on Safari mobile because of same reason.